# How to loop with Python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I was planning to do a Hostname to Ip script using socket.gethostbyname() but it seems like it's not functioning

I've tried to input the host's list from a .txt file and loop through it, it worked only when there is no more than one host in the list which that makes it trash. I tried combining the hosts into one python-list but the gethostbyname() function cannot accept it

```py
f = open("host.txt", "r")

contents = f.readlines()

for content in contents:

    print(content) # Debugging

    try:
        output = socket.gethostbyname(content)
        print(output)

    except:
        print("ERROR!");
f.close()
```

When the text file has one host it works fine but when I add like :

youtube.com
google.com

the output is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockets.py", line 16, in <module>
    output = socket.gethostbyname(content)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `readlines()` include the newline characters (`\n` or `\r\n`) of every line in the file, so you are actually passing `'youtube.com\n'` to `gethostbyname()`.

Using `strip()` on the parameter will remove any trailing whitespace:

```py
output = socket.gethostbyname(content.strip())
```

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate that it worked fine after adding .strip I was struggling there for days!